# Elasticserach combining edge-nGram with synonym-analyzer

Tags: post, elasticsearch, autocomplete

i'm working on a autocompletion-search-microservice based on ElasticSearch. The aim is to prevent duplicated entries. Therefore the service should be resistent against typos and misspellings, what i want to achieve with the edge-nGram filter. So far it is working quite nice und efficient. 
Now the next task is to recognize synonyms. I configured the synonym filter and this works fine too.

But i want to combine these two. The service should first find typos and then synonyms of the corrected form.
Example: The user enters the german word "Prufung" (correctly spelled "Prüfung", which means exam in english). Now my service matches all documents with "Prüfung", but it should also match all documents with synonyms of "Prüfung", the corrected (found word in documents) form, e.g. "test" or "Klassenarbeit" and all other defined synonyms in the dict.

Is it possible to concat the two analyzer the way described above? At the moment both are working with multi_match and fields, but not "working together".

Thanks for help.

Edit:
This is my (test) index:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms_path": "synonyms/german_synonyms.txt"
        },
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With theses mappings:

```
PUT /my_index/_mapping/test
{
  "test": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "fields": {
          "ngram": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard",
            "boost": 1
          },
          "synonym": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard",
            "search_analyzer": "my_synonyms",
            "boost": 0.5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now i enter some data:

```
POST /my_index/test
{
  "name": "Prüfung"
}
```

1) Searching with a typo:

```
GET /my_index/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Prufung", 
      "fields": [
        "name.ngram",
        "name.synonym"],
      "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
  }
}
```

(u instead of ü) with the result:

```
{
  "took": 26,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.67509395,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "AVxFrd_M_ZFx6PmfIobY",
        "_score": 0.67509395,
        "_source": {
          "name": "prüfung"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2) Searching for "test" instead of prüfung (synonym) gives the same result as above.

What i want is:

Searching for tesd (searching with a typo) but it should match Prüfung (the synonym for the correct spelled test) aswell.

Comment: This is too vague and would require too many guesses to try and find out what's not working for you. I suggest creating a gist with the index mapping (including the custom analyzers) with some sample documents and queries that work and don't work. It would be much easier for anyone here to help you.

Comment: I updated the question above, maybe now it is better to understand what i aim to achieve